# VB.net JSON String Deserialize

Tags: vb.net

I'm new at programming and need a push in the right direction.

I want to create a small trivia program that generates a random question with four possible answers. When the correct button is clicked the score has to increase with x. By clicking the button Next a new question is shown
(so 2 Labels, 5 buttons).

Now I found this link (https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=3) which gives me the random questions/answers I need.

I figured out how to this information into a string. Now I need help to get the right information to the label and buttons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ButtonNextQuestion_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonNextQuestion_Click.Click

        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim json As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
    End Sub
End Class

    Public Class Result
        Public Property category As String
        Public Property type As String
        Public Property difficulty As String
        Public Property question As String
        Public Property correct_answer As String
        Public Property incorrect_answers As String()
    End Class

    Public Class Quiz
        Public Property response_code As Integer
        Public Property results As Result()
    End Class
```

JSON example:

```
{
  "response_code": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "easy",
      "question": "In the game Half-Life, which enemy is showcased as the final boss?",
      "correct_answer": "The Nihilanth",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Dr. Wallace Breen",
        "G-Man",
        "The Gonarch"
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "History",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "medium",
      "question": "The creator of the Enigma Cypher and Machine was of what nationality?",
      "correct_answer": "German",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "American",
        "British",
        "Polish"
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Science & Nature",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "medium",
      "question": "What part of the brain takes its name from the Greek for seahorse?",
      "correct_answer": "Hippocampus",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Cerebellum",
        "Thalamus",
        "Amygdala"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to programming I would advice you to work with vb.net on the MVC,
especially when you are going to use JSON because, MVC works very nice with JSON.

Only thing you need is to create a class with the same structure and pass it from the controller to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using json.net ( https://www.newtonsoft.com/json ) to parse json into objects, if the jSON comes from various sources (eg file system)

Once referencing that (isntall it via nuget is)

```
Dim quiz As Quiz = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Quiz)(json)
```

Or even better i find for linvoking APIs RestSharp (restsharp.org ... install it via nuget)

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://opentdb.com/")
Dim request = New RestRequest("api.php", Method.GET)
request.AddParameter("amount", "10")
Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
Dim content = response.Content
Dim response2 As RestResponse(Of Quiz) = client.Execute(Of Quiz)(request)
Dim results = response2.Data.Results
```